# Redux Form - How to handle default selections on async select fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have 3 components: UserProfile, CountryControl and StateControl. I have it setup so the CountryControl and StateControl are responsible for issuing their own ajax requests for data (via actions). When Country changes, the States should be fetched. UserProfile passes a callback to CountryControl so I can tell States to update when Country changes.

Now this works, but relies on the onChange event of the Country selection input to determine when to load States. This is fine except on initial load with an existing UserProfile. Since there is no onChange event fired when Redux Form injects initial values to the Field component I don't have a list of States until I change Country and change back.

Is there a way to either trigger the onChange event when Redux sets the form values - or perhaps when countries are loaded to trigger the onChange?

The parent UserProfile component:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    service.getUserIdentity(userId, (userProfile) => {
      this.props.initialize(userProfile);
    });

  onCountryChanged(e, input) {
    // dispatch a call to update states when selection changes
    input.onChange(e);
    this.props.dispatch(getStates(e.target.value));
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Field
          id = "name"
          label = "Name"
          placeholder = "John Doe"
          name = "name"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <StateControl />
        <CountryControl onSelectChanged={this.onCountryChanged} />
    </div>
  }

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="control-group">
        <div className="control-label">{field.label}</div>
        <div className="controls">
          <input {...field.input} type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} className="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { userProfile: state.userProfile };
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate: validate,
  form: 'UserProfile'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UserProfile)
);
```

The child country control:

```
class CountryControl extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCountries();
  }

  render() {
    const { countries } = this.props;
    return (
      <Field
          label = "Country"
          name = "country"
          component = {this.renderSelect}
          data = {countries}
          onCustomChange = {this.props.onSelectChanged.bind(this)}
      >
      </Field>
    );
  }

  renderSelect(field) {
    return (
      <div className="control-group">
        <div className="control-label">{field.label}</div>
        <div className="controls">
          <select 
            className="form-control"
            onChange={e => {field.onCustomChange(e, field.input) }}
            value={field.input.value}
           >
            <option value=""></option>
            {Array.isArray(field.data) ? field.data.map(option =>
              <option 
                value={option.countryCode} 
                key={option.countryCode}>{option.name}</option>) : ''}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { countries: state.countries };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'UserProfile'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getCountries })(CountryControl)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works, but I bet there's a better way.
In the CountryControl I can manually fire a change event on the select box after the getCountries ajax call completes.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // load data and bind
  this.props.getCountries().then(() => {
    // trigger the onChange event
    var element = document.getElementsByName('country')[0];
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
      element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else{
      element.fireEvent("onchange");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to wrap `<UserProfile />` in a component which on mount, fetches the initial values.

With this approach, you'd even be able to fetch the user => country => state info necessary all before the for even renders so you don't need to manually trigger an onChange.

Comment: not a bad idea. I had added a statement within the render method to make sure country/state doesn't get loaded before loading the userprofile (race condition) but it didn't seem very clean. I was actually trying to avoid fetching it all beforehand so the components could be mostly isolated - but I couldn't figure out how to do that with redux alone.